# Does iOS support registering for an event and have my application run or run code on said event?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

My app needs to know when Bluetooth or USB power is disconnected from the device and inform the user or admin. Can I listen for an iOS event like, Bluetooth.DISCONNECTED (pseudo code) and then run my code (with or without opening my application)? I don't always need the application to open completely just do some tasks for the user that they can access later?

For example, with geo fences I need to be able listen for when the user has entered a location, check if it's something the user wants my app to respond to and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

no there are no events for bt/usb power you could use